# Having trouble copying text from PDF files

Tags: macos, pdf, copy-paste

I’m using Mac Yosemite.  I am not able to copy text from a PDF document and paste it to other applications.  I have tried with both the Google Chrome PDF plugin and Acrobat Reader (v. Acrobat Reader 2015.010.20056).  In Reader, when I highlight text, right-clicking yields only the “Lookup Selected Word” in the menu and the Edit menu has the “Copy” option disabled, even though there is highlighted text.  Any advice on how I can cut and paste from PDF docs on my Mac?

Thanks, - Dave

Comment: Have you checked whether  the file you are reading is protected by copyright?

Comment: Did you also try the app provided by Apple, Preview?  Are you unable to do this with any pdf, or just a particular one?  Does that particular one by chance have Chinese or other non-Latin text?

Comment: Actually I hadn't thought of Preview.  When I open the document in there, I am able to cut and paste just fine.